# UIStoryBoard - Prevent View from overlapping status bar (iOS 11 App)

Tags: swift, iphone, storyboard, ios11, xcode9

I want to stop overlapping of my View with statusbar

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use Auto Layout and pin your view to Top Layout Guide, or use the new Safe Area Layout Guides. To enable it, in your storyboard's File inspector tick the following option.

[image]

As an example I have used gray image view:

[image]

As you can see below, it does not overlap status bar:

[image]

Comment: Can you share more details?

Comment: I tried adding safe area to all my VC and it automatically took spacing from safe area instead of layout guide but when I run the app the view still start above the red line mentioned in the question.

Comment: I would have to see the storyboard and constraint to be able to help you.

Comment: I had to change the constant to 0 for the "Align Top to: Safe Area" constraint. It was at -20. The -20 might have been automatically set due to clicking the "Use Safe Area Layout Guides".

Comment: What can I do if I don't have a storyboard ?

Comment: Off topic: How do you show the iPhone X in storyboard ?, I do not get it that way (I see it simply rectangular)

Comment: At the bottom there's "View as: ..." button, if you click it, you can select few options.