# Status Bar Hidden in Storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, statusbar

Xcode won't display the status bar, how can I fix it ?
Thats what I Have :
[image]

Comment: enable it in general tab

Comment: What version of Xcode are you using ?

Comment: It’s enabled yet, I’m using XCode 9.0.1, the latest version

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your status bar style may be set to light.
You can update it to default (black) in the General configuration of your target in the section Deployment.

[Deployment section of configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCfkn.png)

Comment: This is not correct. Even with the status bar style set to 'Default', no status bar preview appears in the storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Xcode9 than status bar is not showing in Storyboard but when you run application it will show in simulator.

Comment: That’s it, I can see the status bar in the simulator but is there any way to show in the storyboard ?

Comment: I think there is no any option to show status bar in storyboard in Xcode 9.

Answer (score 0):

The Xcode9 storyboard doesn't show status bar but try running the app in simulator i believe u will get status bar.

Comment: So how can I Display correctly the element if I don’t see the status bar ?

Comment: Try changing the value of "status bar" from light to default. Check if it works

Comment: Done but nothing happened

Comment: btw what you mean with elements ? the content ?

Comment: Yes, the content

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46275652/how-to-prevent-app-from-overlapping-status-bar-in-ios-11-iphone-x-xcode-9

is this what you are asking ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157510/discussion-between-rahim-khalid-and-erwann-bestard).